# Variables según el $_GET con dos opciones en PHP

Tags: php

Me gustaría una mano para poder arreglar el script que escribí de forma novata o amateur, la idea es que al elegir una opción y nombre se muestre la variable que corresponda a la opción.

```
script?opcion1=CARTOON
$variable1 = "variable1_cartoon"
script?opcion2=STAR
$variable2 = "variabla2_star"
```

El script que tengo hecho es algo así

````
if($opcion_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["opcion1"]) || $opcion_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["opcion2"])){
    if ($opcion_solicitado == "CARTOON") {
        $variable1_ID = "variable1_cartoon";
        $variable2_ID = "variable2_cartoon";
    }
    elseif ($opcion_solicitado == "DISNEY") {
        $variable1_ID = "variable1_disney";
        $variable2_ID = "variable2_disney";
    }
    elseif ($opcion_solicitado == "STAR") {
        $variable1_ID = "variable1_star";
        $variable2_ID = "variable2_star";
    }
}

if($opcion_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["opcion1"])){
    echo $variable1_ID;
}

if($opcion_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["opcion2"])){
    echo $variable2_ID;
}
?>```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo crearía mi propia estructura de datos, y buscaría en ella el valor de cada variable.

Las ventajas son varias:

- Código organizado y adaptado a una regla de negocio
- Simplificación
- Fácil de mantener
- Diseño flexible que se adapta a futuros cambios modificando solamente la estructura de datos.

Aquí simplemente creamos un array y obtenemos los valores de cada variable según lo que haya en el `$_GET`. Para evitar los casos de `Undefined index` daremos una opción por defecto que he llamado `DEFAULT`, la cual asignaremos a `$option` cuando no esté seteada ni `opcion1` ni `opcion2`. Para determinar esto he usado el *Operador de fusión de null* (disponible desde PHP 7), si trabajas con PHP 5 determinar el valor de `$option` de otro modo, eso es lo de menos.

Veamos:

```
#Estructura de datos
$mData=array
    (
        "CARTOON"=> array ("v1"=>"Carton1",  "v2"=>"Carton2"),
        "DISNEY"=>  array ("v1"=>"Disney1",  "v2"=>"Disney2"),
        "STAR"=>    array ("v1"=>"Star1",    "v2"=>"Star2"),
        "DEFAULT"=> array ("v1"=>"Default1", "v2"=>"Default2")
    );
```

**Ahora viene lo bueno**: te olvidas de todos los `if` presentes y futuros, pudiendo resolver esto con tres líneas de ćodigo:

```
$option= $_GET['opcion1'] ?? $_GET['opcion2'] ?? 'DEFAULT';
$variable1_ID = $mData[$option]['v1'];
$variable2_ID = $mData[$option]['v2'];
echo $variable1_ID, "\n", $variable2_ID;
```

**Salida (algo parecido a esto, según el caso):**

```
Carton1
Carton2
```

Imagina que se necesita otra posibilidad... pues la agregas a `$mData` y el código seguiría funcionando **sin ninguna otra modificación**.

---

#### Post-Data

Si se necesita obtener dos variables, por cada opción, entonces deberás crear una clave por cada valor. Algo así:

```
$option1= $_GET['opcion1'] ?? 'DEFAULT';
$option2= $_GET['opcion2'] ?? 'DEFAULT';

$variable1_ID = $mData[$option1]['v1'];
$variable2_ID = $mData[$option2]['v2'];
echo $variable1_ID, "\n", $variable2_ID;
```

Comment: Qué tal A. Cedano, si quisiera consultar una misma variable pero escrito de otra forma o con otra palabra se podrá con la estructura de datos?. Lo se que se puede hacer haciendo `$opcion_solicitado == "CARTOON" || $opcion_solicitado == "cartoon" || $opcion_solicitado == "caricaturas"` por ejemplo.

Comment: @Daniel revisa la **Post-Data** al final de la respuesta. Si no es eso lo que quieres me dices. Si quieres dotar al código de una opción *case insentitive* la estructura de datos es otra gran ventaja al respecto, pues podrías definir en tu regla de negocio por ejemplo que en `$mData` *todas las claves de array estarán en minúscula* (o en mayúscula) y convertir los índices a todo minúscula al momento de crearlos... así evitas todos los if, los OR y demás.

Comment: me parece genial toda la estructura de datos y lo del post-data es lo que buscaba y me será útil, a lo que me refiero es para obtener las variables de CARTOON utilizando otro nombre por ejemplo `script.php?option1=DIBUJOS` sin tener que añadir DIBUJOS a en $mData repitiendo las variables de CARTOON en la estructura de datos

Comment: @Daniel no logro entender el final de tu comentario. En `$mData` se asigna un valor a cada clave: `CARTOON`, `STAR`, etc. Si quieres hacer trabajar el código con una nueva clave llamada `DIBUJOS` solamente tienes que agregar un nuevo array dentro de `$mData` definiendo allí las variables para esa nueva clave. En eso consiste la flexibilidad de este código precisamente.

Comment: Sería agregar esto en `$mData`  y el código se adapta a la nueva situación sin ningún cambio en niguna otra parte: `"DIBUJOS" => array ("v1"=>"Dibujos1", "v2=>"Dibujos2 o lo que sea necesario"),`

Comment: Si quisiera que que  `CARTOON ` y  `DIBUJOS ` tuvieran los mismos valores, tendría que agregar un nuevo array dentro de `$mDate` teniendo entonces dos array con los mismos valores, es posible hacer un llamado desde ambas claves y obtener un mismo valor?

Comment: Sí, tienes que hacerlo así, @Daniel. Y, si tienes que repetir eso muchas veces, entonces es posible que haya un error de lógica en tu diseño o modelo de datos y tengas que mejorarlo o implementar lógica para que te agrupe los datos a otro nivel. Esta es otra ventaja de trabajar en forma estructurada, que te permite ver errores que no son tan fáciles de ver a simple vista (de lógica, de diseño, etc). Pero es un tema muy amplio. Lo que llama la atención aquí es precisamente ¿por qué dos claves deben asumir un mismo valor? ¿acaso donde se generan esas claves no habrá que cuidar la no redundancia?

Comment: Una solución para evitar duplicados en la estructura de datos sería igualar `DIBUJOS` a `CARTOON` de algún modo (pensemos en un código basado en varios idiomas). Hablaríamos entonces de algo más avanzado que sería la **Internacionalización** de tu código. Si tú trabajas de forma estructurado eso no será demasiado frustrante, pues incorporarías un módulo de traducciones, donde `CARTOON` equivaldría a `DIBUJOS` en castellano, `ESTRELLA` a `STAR`, etc. No sé si sea el caso, pero una de las vías de solución aquí podría ser esa, internacionalizar el código. Y no digamos nada si son varios idiomas.